# Reduce method and promises

Tags: javascript, promise, lodash, reduce

I get an issue using `_.reduce` and promises.

I need to use promises to get my items, and I'd like to use a `_.reduce` to modify the content of the result with an other promise.

**My code :**

```
StripeJs.getBalanceTransactions = function(locals, gte, lte) {
  return stripe.balanceTransactions.list().then(function(balanceTransactions) {

    let payoutsBalanceTransactions = _.filter(balanceTransactions.data, { type: 'payout' });

    payoutsBalanceTransactions = _.reduce(payoutsBalanceTransactions, function(arr, payoutBalanceTransaction) {
      stripe.balanceTransactions.retrieve(payoutBalanceTransaction.id).then(function(subItems) {
        payoutBalanceTransaction.subitems = subItems;

        console.log(payoutBalanceTransaction); // works !

        arr.push(balanceTransactions);
      });
      return arr;
    }, []);

    console.log(payoutsBalanceTransactions); // does not work, array empty

    return Promise.resolve(payoutsBalanceTransactions);
  });
};
```

Comment: the issue is with asynchrony - the reduce will have executed all the way through before any of the `.then(function(subItems) {` code runs - put some console.logs in there and see I'm right

Comment: I don't see you reducing anything, and if you just want to wait for an array of promises, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: are you using reduce so that each `stripe.balanceTransactions.retrieve` is run after the previous one has finished? i.e. can they be run "all at once", or one at a time?

Comment: by the way, should `arr.push(balanceTransactions);` be `arr.push(payoutBalanceTransaction)` ? it seems odd to be pushing `balanceTransactions` multiple times

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is that you push the results into an array in an asynchronous callback. So the `payoutsBalanceTransactions` array stays empty until the callbacks are triggered. You `console.log(payoutsBalanceTransactions)` the contents before before the array is filled, which is why the array is empty.

If you don't mind using [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) cleanest solution is probably:

```
StripeJs.getBalanceTransactions = async function (locals, gte, lte) {
  const transaction = await stripe.balanceTransactions.list();
  const payouts = _.filter(transactions, { type: 'payout' });

  await Promise.all(payouts.map(async function (payout) {
    const items = await stripe.balanceTransactions.retrieve(payout.id);
    payout.subitems = items;
  }));

  console.log(payouts);

  return payouts;
};
```

I've renamed some variables because some of them where quite long. If you can't or don't want to use `async`/`await` things get a bit more tricky.

```
StripeJs.getBalanceTransactions = function (locals, gte, lte) {
  return stripe.balanceTransactions.list()
  .then(function (transactions) {
    const payouts = _.filter(transactions, { type: 'payout' });
    return Promise.all(payouts.map(function (payout) {
      return stripe.balanceTransactions.retrieve(payout.id)
      .then(function (items) {
        payout.subitems = items;
        return payout;
      });
    }));
  })
  // This last `then()` is only here for logging, you can remove it
  // entirely if you don't need the `console.log()` any more.
  .then(function (payouts) {
    console.log(payouts);
    return payouts;
  });
};
```

For a better understanding of promises and asynchronous code in general I suggest reading the [Using Promises guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).